# Как установить/включить расширение openssl для php 5.4

Tags: openssl, php5

Linux Debian 10.
Расширение openssl для php установлено:

```
root@myserver:~# whereis openssl
openssl: /usr/bin/openssl /usr/include/openssl /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz
```

и доступно для всех версий php: 5.6.40 и выше (7.0, 7.1, 7.4). А для php 5.4.45 оно не доступно (его нет в списке доступных расширений.

Как его установить/включить/активировать для данной "древней" версии?